# Aggregating http requests with forwarding (http buffer service)

Tags: software-development, web-services, cloud-service, http

I have an existing web server with limited capaticies and many clients (background daemons). They are sending requests every few seconds. Request's body is simple json content:

```
{
    "client_id": 1,
    "value": 234711234,
    "updated": "2017-09-02T14:15:42.107Z"
}
```

I want to introduce service in a middle (http buffer) that will collect requests from all clients and forward only fresh in one bunch request every 10 seconds.

E.g. if this service receive this requests in 10 seconds:

```
{
    "client_id": 1,
    "value": 10,
    "updated": "2017-01-01T00:00:01.000Z"
}
{
    "client_id": 2,
    "value": 20,
    "updated": "2017-01-01T00:00:02.000Z"
}
{
    "client_id": 1,
    "value": 30,
    "updated": "2017-01-01T00:00:03.000Z"
}
{
    "client_id": 1,
    "value": 40,
    "updated": "2017-01-01T00:00:04.000Z"
}
```

it should send this request to main server after this time:

```
[
    {
        "client_id": 2,
        "value": 20,
        "updated": "2017-01-01T00:00:02.000Z"
    },
    {
        "client_id": 1,
        "value": 40,
        "updated": "2017-01-01T00:00:04.000Z"
    }
]
```

Is there any existing service or tool that can do this work?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know any such tool though, you might have to develop it, as the JSON syntax seems to be unique to your project (please tell us if not).